# Record the timestamps of slide changes during a live Powerpoint presentation?

Tags: streaming

I am planning to implement a lecture capture solution. One of the requirements is to record both the presenter and the slideshow. The presenter is recorded with a videocamera obviously, and the slideshow will probably be captured using a tool like Camtasia.

Now during playback three components are visible: the presenter, the slides and a table of contents. Clicking a chapter title in the TOC causes the video to navigate to the corresponding section. This means that a mapping must be made between chapter titles and their timestamps in the video.

Usually a change of topic is accompanied with a slide change in the Powerpoint presentation. So the timestamps could be deduced from the slidechanges. However, this requires me to detect slide changes during the live presentation. And I don't know how to do that.

Anyone here knows how to do detect slide changes? Is there a Powerpoint API where I can connect event handlers or something like that? I'd greatly appreciate your help!

**Edit**
This issue is no longer relevant for my current work so this question will not be updated by me. However, you are still  free to help others by posting your answers/insights here.

Comment: I'm currently working on other aspects of this application. I'll look further into some time later. Your link to the Interop post seems interesting, but I haven't fully checked it out yet. (The video triggers aren't useful though.)

Comment: I opened the bounty to get more people sharing their ideas. There may be multiple valid approaches for solving this problem. However, code samples are welcome too :)

Comment: @StackedCrooked: does the answer below answer your question?

Comment: @Otaku, I'm sorry but I never tried out your suggestion because I found a new job.

Comment: congrats on the new job! i'll flag to mods to see if the post can be closed.

Comment: I can close as "Too Localized" since this question was only relevant during your last job. @StackedCrooked, please indicate whether you would like me to do so.

Comment: @Jonathan, it may be useful to leave this post open because new replies might be helpful for other people. However, since better answers than the ones that have already been posted are unlikely to appear I guess it won't do much harm to close this question. So do as you please :)

Comment: @StackedCrooked - Entirely up to you, man :)

Comment: @Jonathan, then leave it open. Maybe someone will post something interesting here some day...

Comment: no need for me to keep my solution here if it has no chance of being accepted as the correct answer, so it's been deleted. maybe turn this into a wiki?

Answer (score 3):

Here's some code that will get you most of the way there.

First, in PowerPoint VBE, create a class, call it **clsPPTEvents**. Put the following inside:

```
Public WithEvents PPTEvent As Application
Private Sub PPTEvent_SlideShowNextSlide(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
    MsgBox "Position: " & Wn.View.CurrentShowPosition & ", Time: " & Time
End Sub
```

Then create a module, call it anything, and put the following inside:

```
Public newPPTEvents As New clsPPTEvents
Sub StartEvents()
    Set newPPTEvents.PPTEvent = Application
End Sub
Sub EndEvents()
    Set newPPTEvents.PPTEvent = Nothing
End Sub
```

By then running the `StartEvents` sub, you can go into presentation mode and on every slide change, the slide number (position) and current time of the change will be displayed in a message box. You can use these (or other) variables to write to a file. Upon exiting the running slide show, you can then run `EndEvents` to stop the API hook.

Comment: I need to implement a solution that works for previous versions of PowerPoint as well. Besides, I don't see how the video trigger feature could help me in recording timestamps of slide-changes?

I'll check out the Interop functionality though.

Answer (score 2):

It would be elegant to detect the slide changes, but wouldn't it be more practical to have the presenter to type a hotkey whenever there is a topic change? Or anything similar, but cooperating with the presenter, since he knows best when the topic changes.

Sorry not to provide an elegant answer.